# How to change bootstrap 4 grid system to fit mobile elegantly

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, media-queries, razor-pages

I have 3 steps form and in each row in it contains many inputs like this[click here to see my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68uu3.png)  
and here a sample of the gird system i used

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="col">
<input asp-for="First_Name_AR" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col">
<input asp-for="Second_Name_AR" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col">
<input asp-for="Father_Name_AR" class="form-control" />
</div>
</div>
```

the problem when using mobile it will be like this : [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvR1j.png)

So what I want is to make this form fit mobile beautifully **like to set one input in each row** like this

```
  <div class="row">
<div class="col">
<input asp-for="First_Name_AR" class="form-control" />
</div>
    </div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<input asp-for="Second_Name_AR" class="form-control" />
</div>
    </div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<input asp-for="Father_Name_AR" class="form-control" />
</div>
    </div>
```

is there any idea using @media query or javascript solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/) wrong. You put each `col` in a separate `row`. Instead, put all columns inside the same row. Then change the class from `col` to `col-md-4`.

The class `col-md-4` means the following:

- If the viewport width >= 768px: there will be three columns beside each other.
- If the viewport width < 768px: columns will be stacked above each other.

See the snippet below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input asp-for="First_Name_AR" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input asp-for="Second_Name_AR" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input asp-for="Father_Name_AR" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```